# Install R in ubuntu wily

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am having problems with `R` after updating to `ubuntu 15.10`:

When I trying to run `R`, I got the following:

> /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libicui18n.so.52: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

And If I tried to uninstall `R` (someone suggest that in the web) it doesn't remove the `R` binary (not even using `purge`!)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into that with a CRAN package but it could possibly be the same for R itself.  When you upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, the ICU libraries goes from 52 to 55.

And all binaries built outside the package management systems may fail as `libicu52` is now longer there.  So you need to rebuild -- and it will pick up `libicu55`.

But you should **really** consider using the (always current) R binaries from [the CRAN mirrors](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu).  These reflect the Debian binaries I upload, and which Michael rebuilds.  Lots of people use them happily, and we have the `r-sig-debian` list for help if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I just recompiled `R` from the source (I want to emphasize this: **recompiled** from the source) and it worked.

1. Download R from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.2.tar.gz
2. Uncompress it: `tar zxvf R-3.2.2.tar.gz`
3. `cd R-3.2.2`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`

**UPDATE**

After following some suggestions I remove the `R`-installed from the source  with `sudo make uninstall`. And then I installed it from `synaptic`, and now everything worked.

Comment: the problem is that `Rstudio` is not working ... `:(`

Comment: Are you, actually, try to find r-cran pacakges into repository, for example, like this: apt-cache search "^r-.*" | sort

Comment: That answer, while technically correct, ignores a) that we prefer package management solutions and b) that CRAN binary for the distro has some added-value tweaks.

Comment: Could you share what are the _added-value tweaks_?

Comment: @Hamsternik it didn't remove the  binary or the linking

Comment: @nanounanue it just search all packages relating to r-cran packages, include R.

Comment: You can look [at the diff of the package](http://packages.debian.org/package=r-base). I am partial to many things, including the bash completion, the live-switching of BLAS/LAPACK, the fact that all `capabilities()` are supported and more.